# Pass data from one component to another component in angular

Tags: angular

I really need your help as I am passing data from one component to another and based on that hide the div. See below image

[image]

I am calling below component and setting their values but it gives following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

Ask question, I can share the details too.

I also tried the Injectable method but it was not working. May be I am doing something wrong.

**Code Snippet Parent Component**

```
import { HelpGuideComponent} from '../shared/component/help-guide/help-guide.component';

// Call the component
public help_guide: HelpGuideComponent;
```

on click of above icon following variable from child component I want to set

```
this.help_guide.hidePopOverClass = false;
```

Dialogue is on help guide and above icon is menu component. On each click it should toggle.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code example or at least a snippet of the code you're having an issue with, instead of the image of the UI for your project. We are not going to be able to help based off of the image.

Comment: you can use @ViewChild to make the other component changes

Comment: Add some of your code does help figure out what are you doing

Comment: Code snippet added.

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between components is done with Services. I would suggest creating a service that can handle getting your default values, and using a Observable to watch for event changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Behavior Subject. Read more about the subject: https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#behaviorsubject

Put it in a service file so can share these two components.
for example, in app.service.ts:

```
buttonSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true) //default value is true, which  means to show the dialog content at first
```

in that button component, when clicks on the button, pass false value.

```
this.appService.buttonSubject.next(false)
```

in your HelpGuideComponent, subscribe to it:

```
this.appService.buttonSubject.subscribe(value =>{ this.help_guide.hidePopOverClass = value })
```

to explain more from the above link:

> It stores the latest value emitted to its consumers, and whenever a
> new Observer subscribes, it will immediately receive the "current
> value" from the BehaviorSubject.

The value changes whenever you change it by `subject.next()`